# jquery ui datepicker range open date 2 automatic after date1 selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use JQuery ui datepicker range for booking check in - check out, i need that after user selected check in date the check out calendar will automatic open for choose date 2. I am using standard jQuery UI datepicker.

```
jQuery(function() {

var dateToday = new Date();

jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
  defaultDate: '+1w', 
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: false,
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonImage: calendarUrl,
  showOn: 'both',
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  minDate: dateToday
  });
jQuery('#from').datepicker({onSelect: function() {
      var date = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
      if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
      jQuery('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
}});
jQuery('#to').datepicker({onSelect: function() {
      var date = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
      if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
      }
      //jQuery('#from').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
}});
});
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using so we can suggest something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this with your on select method of 'from' datepicker.

Add this line after initialzing the 'to' datepicker

```
jQuery('#from').datepicker({
onClose: function(){
    var date = jQuery(this).datepicker('getDate');
    if (date) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    jQuery('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
    jQuery('#to').datepicker('show');
}});
```

Comment: its open my calendar but close it after sec

Comment: I have edited my answer. Instead of using onSelect to initialize the 'to' datepicker and show it. Try using the onClose method to do that. I have verified my answer as well now. Please check on your end